How to preserve contrast/highlights when converting ProRes HDR 10-bit to SDR using hevc_videotoolbox?
I'm trying to convert a 4K HDR 10-bit video clip to BT.709, preserving as much color as possible while allowing the clip to be played where HDR is not supported.
With the command below, the output is generally passable to most, but I aim for it to be as close to the original as possible. At the moment, colors appear
My current command:
ffmpeg -i input.mov \
-c:v hevc_videotoolbox \
-q:v 72 \
-profile:v main10 \
-g 1 \
-tag:v hvc1 \
-vf "zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=pc,format=yuv420p10le" \
-map 0:v -map 0:a \
output.mp4

Please note that I'm using hevc_videotoolbox over libx265 at the moment due to its hardware acceleration. I'm encoding on a 2021 MacBook Pro with M1 Pro, so the former encodes about 30x faster than the standard x265 library.
I've tried the following solutions:

Added libplacebo=contrast_recovery=0.4 to the end of the -vf filter array; I don't think it did anything.
Appended eq=gamma=1.1 to the beginning of the -vf filter array; increased the gamma, but it looked too artificially bright if that makes sense. I may have set the gamma filter too high, in retrospect.
Swapped tonemap=hable with tonemap=mobius; looked much worse.

Here's the relevant mediainfo of my input file:
Format                                   : ProRes
Format version                           : Version 0
Format profile                           : 422 HQ
Codec ID                                 : apch
Duration                                 : 3 min 35 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 417 Mb/s
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Scan type                                : Progressive
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Scan type                                : Progressive
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant

Here's an image album I made comparing the 4 encodes I've narrowed down, with 1 png containing the 4 screenshots tiled in a 2x2 grid. I also uploaded them individually to an image comparison site, which you can click here to see, allowing you to click to cycle through each screenshot.
Should I be doing something differently in my filtering or overall command, or is this as close as I'll get? Is there a better way to preserve the color vibrancy when encoding from BT.2020? I understand I won't be able to perfectly replicate the color vibrancy of HDR, but I'd like to get as close as possible (while also learning more about encoding in general, I'm fairly new to ffmpeg and the libraries it uses.)
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
